# Doubts about bash script efficiency

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk

I have to accomplish a relatively simple task, basically i have an enormous amount of files with the following format

"2014-01-27","07:20:38","data","data","data"

Basically i would like to extract the first 2 fields, convert them into a unix epoch date, add 6 hours to it (due timezone difference), and replace the first 2 original columns with the resulting milliseconds (unix epoch, since 19700101 converted to mills)
I have written a script that works fine, well, the issue is that is very very slow, i need to run this over 150 files with a total line count of more then 5.000.000 and i was wondering if you had any advice about how could i make it faster, here it is:

```
    #!/bin/bash

function format()
{
while read line; do
 entire_date=$(echo ${line} | cut -d"," -f1-2);
 trimmed_date=$(echo ${entire_date} | sed 's/"//g;s/,/ /g');
 seconds=$(date -d "${trimmed_date} + 6 hours" +%s);
 millis=$((${seconds} * 1000));
 echo ${line} | sed "s/$entire_date/\"$millis\"/g" >> "output"
done < $*
}

format $*
```

Comment: The Unix epoch is seconds, not milliseconds.  It is traditionally a (long?) integer, but representations with a decimal part have been used to represent sub-second precision.

Comment: You should be using `"$@"` instead of `$*`.  Your code is currently unable to process file names with spaces in them, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the exist function `mktime` in awk, tested, it is faster than perl.

```
awk  '{t=$2 " " $4;gsub(/[-:]/," ",t);printf "\"%s\",%s\n",(mktime(t)+6*3600)*1000,substr($0,25)}' FS=\" OFS=\" file
```

Here is the test result.

```
    $ wc -l file
    1244 file
    $ time awk  '{t=$2 " " $4;gsub(/[-:]/," ",t);printf "\"%s\",%s\n",(mktime(t)+6*3600)*1000,substr($0,25)}' FS=\" OFS=\" file > /dev/null

real    0m0.172s
user    0m0.140s
sys     0m0.046s

    $ time perl -MDate::Parse -pe 'die "$0:$ARGV:$.: Unexpected input $_"
        unless s/(?<=^")([^"]+)","([^"]+)(?=")/ (str2time("$1 $2")+6*3600)*1000 /e' file > /dev/null

real    0m0.328s
user    0m0.218s
sys     0m0.124s
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to avoid external commands (except date) to gain time. Tests show that it is 4 times faster than your code. (Okay, the tripleee's perl solution is 40 times faster than mine !)

```
#! /bin/bash

function format()
{
    while IFS=, read date0 date1 datas; do
        date0="${date0//\"/}"
        date1="${date1//\"/}"
        seconds=$(date -d "$date0 $date1 + 6 hours" +%s)
        echo "\"${seconds}000\",$datas" 
    done
}

output="output.txt"

# Process each file in argument
for file ; do
    format < "$file"
done >| "$output"

exit 0
```

Comment: The initial `read line` is unnecessary; `while IFS=, read date0 date1 datas; do` lets you remove the first line of the body. The final `for` loop can be `for file; do format < "$file"; done > "$output"`, eliminating the need to pre-create the file.

Comment: Thanks! I kept the first read from the original script. Fixed

Comment: For the curious, `>|` is identical to `|`, but allows `"$output"` to be overwritten if it exists and the `noclobber` option is set.

Answer (score 3):

You are spawning a significant number of processes for each input line. Probably half of those could easily be factored away, by quick glance, but I would definitely recommend a switch to Perl or Python instead.

```
perl -MDate::Parse -pe 'die "$0:$ARGV:$.: Unexpected input $_"
    unless s/(?<=^")([^"]+)","([^"]+)(?=")/ (str2time("$1 $2")+6*3600)*1000 /e'
```

I'd like to recommend [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm) but I do not have it installed here, and if you have requirements to not touch the fields after the second at all, it might not be what you need anyway.  This is quick and dirty but probably also much simpler than a "proper" CSV solution.

The real meat is the `str2time` function from [Date::Parse](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-2.30/lib/Date/Parse.pm), which I imagine will be a lot quicker than repeatedly calling `date` (ISTR it does some memoization internally so it can do nearby dates quickly).  The regex replaces the first two fields with the output; note the `/e` flag which allows Perl code to be evaluated in the replacement part.  The `(?<=^")` and `(?=")` zero-width assertions require these matches to be present but does not include them in the substitution operation.  (I originally substituted the enclosing double quotes, but with this change, they are retained, as apparently you want to keep them.)

Change the `die` to a `warn` if you want the script to continue in spite of errors (maybe redirect standard error to a file then!)

Comment: thx, works fast indeed, but is missing the first line of each files, it edits 99999 lines in 4 seconds instead of 9

Comment: I don't see how it could miss the first line, unless you have a header line with field names or something?  If you want to print the first line verbatim, add `next if $. == 1;` before the rest of the script (just before `die`).

Comment: Or maybe `s/","/ / and next if $. == 1;` to just merge the first two fields on the first line.

Comment: @JBoy, not really. Mostly perl runs faster, but not always. See my answer.